# ssh into remote Emacs from Emacs control key problem

Tags: emacs, ssh

When I do split screen in emacs, I sshed into a remote machine's emacs and I can't use the control-x key without calling both original and the remote one at the same time. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really address your problem, but you could circumvent it by running Emacs locally and accessing the remote files via tramp.

If you use the scpc or rsyncc tramp methods, it will attempt to use ControlMaster to maintain a single ssh connection for all communication with that server, which I find makes tramp a very efficient option for remote access, as well as being convenient.